# Hout to send user input to other file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I got two inputs from the user, for signup an account, but I separate the signup screen and the authentication work into two file, how can I pass the input data from `signUp.dart` to `auth.dart`

I using the `onPressed:` to call the function `_signUp()` which set up in `auth.dart`

but how can I pass the data to `_signUp()`?

`signUp.dart`

```
final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();


    body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 
                'Password'),
          ),

          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  signUp();
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
         ],
```

`auth.dart`

```
signUp(){

signUpNewUserOnServer(
  email: emailInputByUser,
  password: passwordInputByUser,
)


}
```

Comment: while your are using `_`, it becomes private. Can you describe more about your code

Comment: @YeasinSheikh How about If I change the function to public?

Comment: yes you can do by removing `_`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh and I have no idea how to pass the data to other file

Answer (score 1):

You can create two parameters(email & password) like

```dart
signUp({
  required String emailInputByUser,
  required String passwordInputByUser,
}) {
  signUpNewUserOnServer(
    email: emailInputByUser,
    password: passwordInputByUser,
  );
}
```

And while using it

```dart
 signUp(emailInputByUser: emailController.text, passwordInputByUser: passwordController.text);
```

You can start from [language-tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program)

Comment: Note: I am not certain about your method's return type.